# Proper permissions for my SVN repository directory tree on Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, svn

I restored my Mac form a Time Machine backup, and now I can't check files into my svn repo.

I have tried svnadmin recover, but it fails:

```
svnadmin: Can't open file 'WriteAssist/db/write-lock': Permission denied
```

The directory is owned by the "admin" user that I set up for bootstrapping the machine. My current user is "andersprivat".

Should I just chown the entire tree? Doing a chmod 777 would presumably work, but seems like a big security hole.

Comment: And you ran `svnadmin recover` as *admin*?

Comment: No, as user andersprivat. Should i sudo it?

Comment: That's the first thing I'd try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end svnadmin recover appeared to do nothing at all for me.

I ended up having to chmod -R 777 all the files to be allowed to check in at all, then manually handling all in-flight issues. Did not leave me loving svn any more than I already did. When it works it's great, but getting it up when it has stumbled is a b*tch.

Comment: I think you did not setup your SVN server properly. The usual setup is to have the SVN server daemon run as the same user that was used to set up the repository.

Comment: I think that what happened was that I restored form Time Machine as user named "admin", and so the ownership of the subversion repo tree changed from my programming user ("andersprivat"). So what happened was that originally it was set up correctly (by XCode), but later it was broken by Time Machine. So "I" did not do anything - the programs dis something on their own.